# HANAMI Reload routes into Rspec Test

Tags: rspec, routes, hanami

Good morning, 
I have a question.
How i can reload my routes into a RSpec Test after change my env variable like i do in rails (Rails.application.reload_routes!)
Thank you!
Gustavo

Comment: What's your env var controlling? Do you have a snippet to share?

Comment: No i dont have, but all i want to know is how i reload my routes with hanami like i do in rails

Comment: There is no way to reload routes in Hanami. But why do you need it? I'm sure there is another way to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Because i did a if conditional into my routes like this example:
`namespace 'mock' do
  get '/foo',    to: 'foo#bar', as: :foo_bar
  get '/bar',            to: 'bar#foo', as: :bar_food
end if AplicationName.settings.Aplication_env == 'development' `
And i expect to not found some routes into my production env
Soo to test my enviroments i need change my AplicationName.settings.Aplication_env and reload my routes to see if they are routable into RSpec

Comment: What's the object under test? `Web.routes`?

Comment: Yes, that`s the object.